# Photoswipe - change sequence of navigation icons required

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, photoswipe

I have a photoswipe gallery, by default, when looking at the full images carousel, the navigation icons at the bottom read :close, previous, next.

I would like to alter this to : previous, close, next.

I initially thought that this would not be much of a problem by altering the photoswipe.css to alter the position by switching the previous and close positioning.

This did not work as the action seems to be attached to the cell as opposed to the image, and all the css is doing is controlling the position of the background image?

Any help appreciated.